# Is there any possible way to access the anonymous inner class method? If no why Java compiler allowing to create this method? In java 11

Tags: java, java-11, anonymous-inner-class

```
class Vehicle{
    public void park(){
        //Do something
    }
}
class Example{
    public static void main(String args[]){
    Vehicle v1=new Vehicle();
    Vehicle v2=new Vehicle(){
        public void park(){
            //Do something
        }
        public void start(){
            //Do something
        }
        //start();
    }/*.start()*/;
    //v2.start();
    }
}
```

//All of those calling for start functions are illegal. Is there a possible way to access start function?

Comment: Only by calling it from within `park()`

Comment: 1) You could call `start` using reflection.  2) You could call `start` in a context where the static type of the the subclass of `Vehicle` hasn't been obscured; e.g. by assigning to a variable of type `Vehicle`.  3) Just don't do it.  4) See the duplicate link for more information.

Comment: Just declare `v2` using `var`, i.e. `var v2 = new Vehicle() { …`